# HTML5 CSS animation to video slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, ffmpeg

I want to create dynamic slideshow using HTML5 animations and later export it to make a video using ffmpeg. Is this idea feasible?

What stack is Animoto using?

Comment: Possible. Export every frame as image and join them in FFMPEG

Comment: html page contains audio and element animation. 
example bullet points (with some animation) and each point has its separate audio

Comment: `ffmpeg` can capture the screen, but the answer depends on your OS which is not mentioned. We don't know what stack Animoto is using: it's a commercial closed-source site, but if you have an output video from from Animoto then we can take a look at it and possibly be able to tell what encoder and/or muxer implementations it uses.